# Django url dispatcher calls the wrong function

Tags: python, django, url, routes

the problem that I have is this one:
I created a new `re_path` in my `urls.py` file, but when I make a request at that url the wrong function is called.

```
# myapp/urls.py
from django.urls import path, re_path
from . import views as multiplayer_lite_views

urlpatterns = [
    # other paths

    re_path(r'vote/(?P<match_id>\w{16})', multiplayer_lite_views.vote, name='multiplayer_lite_vote'),
    re_path(r'nightvote/(?P<match_id>\w{16})', multiplayer_lite_views.night_vote, name='multiplayer_lite_night_vote'),
    path('new-match/', multiplayer_lite_views.new_match, name='multiplayer_lite_new_match'),
    path('', multiplayer_lite_views.home, name='multiplayer_lite_home'),
]
```

what I did was simply duplicate the line `re_path(r'vote/...` and renamed it to `re_path(r'nightvote/...` but changing also all the other info, like `multiplayer_lite_views.vote` to `multiplayer_lite_views.night_vote`.

The problem is that when I go to this url `nightvote/` the function `vote` is called.

```
# myapp/views.py

def vote(request, match_id):
    print('vote function')
    # do other stuff
    return return JsonResponse(...)

def night_vote(request, match_id):
    print('nightvote function')
    # do other stuff
    return return JsonResponse(...)
```

In the server side what I see is that:

```
...
vote function
[18/Mar/2020 10:19:16] "POST /nightvote/gfvkpvhlwlqzosae HTTP/1.1" 200 16
...
```

PS I have already tried to close Django and reopen, the same with vs code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your url re_path like as below:

```
re_path(r'^vote/(?P<match_id>\w{16})$', multiplayer_lite_views.vote, name='multiplayer_lite_vote'),
re_path(r'^nightvote/(?P<match_id>\w{16})$', multiplayer_lite_views.night_vote, name='multiplayer_lite_night_vote'),
```

I had this problem and this was because `^`.